# Views and Templating in Flask with persisted, dynamic forms

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm working on a UI flow that uses several stages of dynamic wtforms constructed from previous form choices and a backend datamodel (as per [this](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/specific_problems.html#dynamic-form-composition)).  My current (novice) approach simply renders each new form in place of the previously submitted form. However, I would like to be able to persist the previous forms and their choices with each new submission so that the overall structure is visible.

Is there a flask pattern for accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone needs this in the future, I found the best way to do this was simply to persist the actual model data once the form had been submitted to a cookie via the flask `session` object, this way each new form / template stage could be a child of the last and the form / view and previous forms could be re-rendered using the data in the session cookie.